# Magnific popup calls 2 confirmation when closed

Tags: magnific-popup

I used magnific popup for form modal. I want confirmation when modal was closed by user. But, the problem is that 2 confirmations are being displayed. I want only one. Here is my code

```
    <a href="#registration" class="popup-modal">
        <span>Register</span>
    </a>

    <div id="registration" class="white-popup-block mfp-hide">
        <button title="Close" type="button" class="mfp-close"><i class="icon-cross" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <div class="mfp-text">
           <!-- My Form Here -->
        </div>
    </div>

$('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
    type: 'inline',
    preloader: false,
    modal: true,
    callbacks: {
        open: function() {
            $.magnificPopup.instance.close = function () {
                if (!confirm("Are you sure?")) {
                    return;
                }
                $.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
            };
        }
    }
});
```

What is the possible problem of my code. Why did the popup when closed shows 2 confirmation dialog? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: i tried you code and i have only 1, maybe your html have another element with `popup-modal` class?

Comment: thanks :)  I solved the issue, there is another close function when I clicked the closed icon, so I remove that function